# How to integrate Angular 6 app with WordPress theme?

Tags: angular, wordpress, angular6, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have already created a full project in `WordPress` but in that one section `Alone` I have developed in `Angular 6` so now I have to integrate both.

Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of serving two separate code bases consider making the Angular App your main theme for a fully integrated experience.

Using Xo for Angular you will be able to combine your existing theme with Angular and manage your Pages and Posts the same way you likely do now. Xo provides an API which makes it easy to interact with your WordPress content, routes for pages and posts are then served dynamically to your Angular App.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Check out the example theme at: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

Most pages will be mostly simple modules/components that can also utilize ACF fields if configured making custom options for a particular template a breeze.

This provides a working example of a WordPress theme written fully in Angular that uses selectable templates, dynamic routes.

Documentation (work in progress): https://angularxo.io/

Plugin github: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core

Full disclosure I am the author of the above plugin and theme.

Let me know if you think this could work for you, thanks!

Comment: Good job, @WarriorRocker! Visiting your page (https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core), I see "Languages": I plan to start now to learn Angular, so I don't know its structure, but is that folder necessary to translate the UI in other languages? In this case I would translate it in Italian: tell me how I can help. I will start by reading your guide (https://angularxo.io/guides), thanks you for this answer!